# Loading variable structured JSON into Google BigQuery, issues with repeating and nullable

Tags: json

I'm trying to load 200k+ JSON files into Google BigQuery. The dataset is cashier data, in some transactions one discount voucher is used, in some more than 1 voucher and in others no voucher is used. So some fields are REPEATABLE in one file, but NULL in the other.

When loading I'm getting an error:

```
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job
'***': Invalid schema update. Field PromoPtn has changed mode from REPEATED to NULLABLE
```

How to handle this in BigQuery?

Comment: Your json files seem to have schema differences. Please provide sample json structure for each transaction type you deal with.

Comment: Hi Jaison, the fact is that potentially every document can have a different json structure up to 150 columns. I tried loading with schema on autodetect, but it's giving the same error. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The input json file that to be loaded MUST match the schema of the Bigquery table.

**Cases that fails:**

- Additional column in json file that is NOT in BigQuery table
- Datatype mismatch
- Null value for REQUIRED fields
- Case difference in field names

**BigQuery allows below case:**

- json file has lesser columns(say your table has 150 but file has 120). However, all 120 columns MUST be in Bigquery table and MUST match the datatype and mode.

Based on my experience, I suggest you understand your json files - identify all possible columns, create a generic schema defining all fields as NULLABLE such that it allows you to load all files despite difference in structure.